# Using matrices as input to convolutional neural network

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to use a convolutional neural network to identify patterns in binary matrices and classify them to one of two classes. At the moment I have a bunch of 15x15 matrices in csv format.

In order to get a handle on how convolutional nets work I have been following [sentdex's tutorials on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mynJtLhhcXk&index=57&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfKTOs3Keq_kaG2P55YRn5v). In this he uses a conv net to classify the MNIST dataset. The code he uses to specify the input is like this:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot = True)

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')
```

My question is how do I set up a file like 'input_data' which the conv net can read my matrices and labels from? Can I include ALL of my training data in one file or do I need to split them into train/test files?

I have set up an excel file in the following format but not sure if it will work in the same way MNIST does.

input data example file:
[image: input data example file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite tutorials are from aymericdamien, below is a link to the convolutional tutorial in jupyter (go back up a few directories in github for all of the tutorials).

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network_raw.ipynb

You'll notice that their input is the same as what you have posted:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_input])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_classes])
```

And the first thing they do in the `conv_net()` function is to reshape it to a image:

```
x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])
```

The shape arguments are understood as follows:

- `-1`: variable batch size
- `28`: height of the image (mnist is 28x28 grayscale images)
- `28`: width of the image
- `1`:  color channels, grayscale images have 1 color channel, RGB images have 3 typically.

Try reshaping the image using numpy and displaying it yourself to check that you got it right:

```
import scipy.misc as misc
import numpy as np
img = np.reshape(flat_image, (28,28,1))
misc.imshow(img)
```

As far as train and test process goes, tensorflow doesn't care anything about your structure. I generally would separate the files to make sure you don't accidentally pass your test set to your training process though. You will ultimately need to call `sess.run` separately on your training and test datasets. I think the tutorial I linked to provides a very good example of this process, so if you have more specific questions I'll leave them to a future post.